# Change only time part of a datetimeoffset in SQL

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, datetimeoffset

How can I set only the time portion of a SQL datetimeoffset variable?

For example:

```
DECLARE @date datetimeoffset = '2014-01-11 11:04:26 +02:00'
```

I want to calculate two further datetimeoffsets:

```
@startdate should be '2014-01-11 00:00:00 +02:00'
@enddate should be '2014-01-12 00:00:00 +02:00'
```

But all the solutions I tried set the offset to zero.

**NOTE**: I need the original offset in the results since I need to compare them to some datetimeoffset columns in a table. So just casting to a date will not work.

**Further note**: This would be quite easy in SQL2012; I could use DATETIMEOFFSETFROMPARTS. Unfortunately, I am not able to upgrade to 2012 at the moment. Example:

```
SET @startdate = SELECT DATETIMEOFFSETFROMPARTS(datepart(yyyy, @date), datepart(mm, @date), datepart(dd, @date), 0, 0, 0, 0, datepart(tz, @date), 0, 7);
```

Comment: If you want to remove the time portion, then use `cast(@startdate as date)`.

Comment: Could you clearly write the code you tried to execute and exact result you expect?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
DECLARE @date DATETIMEOFFSET = '2014-01-11 11:04:26 +02:00'

SELECT @date InputDate,
CONVERT(DATETIMEOFFSET,(CONVERT(VARCHAR(20),CONVERT(DATETIME,(CONVERT(DATETIME,CONVERT(DATE,@date)))) ) + ' ' + RIGHT(@date,6))) StartDate,
CONVERT(DATETIMEOFFSET,(CONVERT(VARCHAR(20),CONVERT(DATETIME,(CONVERT(DATETIME,CONVERT(DATE,DATEADD(day,1,@date))))) ) + ' ' + RIGHT(@date,6))) EndDate
```

Comment: Thank you this works great. Do you mind explaining it a bit more? It seems to piece together a string from the parts of the input date.

Comment: Ok. 
CONVERT(VARCHAR(20),(CONVERT(DATETIME,CONVERT(DATE,@date)))
the above part is used to get the date from the input and convert it into datetime so explicit conversion here makes the time to be 00:00.00

Comment: 2. here am getting offset value from input using string functions (Right function) because datefunction have some restrictions over Timeoffset

Answer (score 7):

```
DECLARE @date DATETIMEOFFSET = '2014-01-11 11:04:26 +02:00'

SELECT TODATETIMEOFFSET(CAST(@date AS date),DATEPART(tz,@date))
SELECT TODATETIMEOFFSET(DATEADD(day,1,CAST(@date AS date)),DATEPART(tz,@date))
```